# How to advance iterator c++ through every character in string

Tags: c++, iterator

What I'm confused about is that I have a map which is made up of size_t of string as the key, and strings as the value.

```
std::multimap<size_t, std::string> wordMap;
```

Then I have a pair that stores the equal_range for all strings with size of 4. Then I want to iterate through the start of that equal_range to the end of that equal_range. The start is my pair.first and end is my pair.second. How would I iterate through every character that my pair.first points too and then compare that to every word in between pair.first and pair.second ?

```
pair<multimap<size_t, string>::iterator, multimap<size_t, string>::iterator> key_range;
key_range = wordMap.equal_range(n);
```

Basically I want to compare every letter in word1 to every character in word2. 
Advance itr2 which is word2 to the next word and compare every letter in that to every letter in word1. Do this for every word then advance itr1 which is word1 to another word and compare that to every word. 
How would I get every character itr2 points to? I think the first for loop accomplishes this for the first iterator but I don't know how to do it for itr2.

```
for (word_map::iterator itr = key_range.first; itr != key_range.second; itr++)   { //this loop will iterate through every word to be compared
for (word_map::iterator itr2 = next(key_range.first); itr2 != key_range.second; itr2++) {  //this loop will iterate through every word being compared against itr1
int i = 0;
int hit = 0;
for (char& c1 : itr->first) { 
            char& c2{ (itr2)->first[i] };
    if(c1 != c2)
    hit++;
 i++;
}
}
```

I'd like to compare every letter in every word against each other as long as they have the same string size.  Then if hit == 1 that means the words are only off by 1 character and they should be mapped or stored in some type of STL container that groups them. I'm still new to STL so i'm thinking a set but I need to read more into it.

Comment: for (word_map::iterator itr2 = *(key_range++).first    is what I tried

Comment: You can use `std::next(key_range.first)` to get the iterator after that one. It won't work if the provided iterator is at the end.

Comment: So, you basically want to compare the first word (pointed to by key_range.first) to every other word (i.e. to every subsequent iterator)?

Comment: Yes. My overall goal is I have a textfile of words which have been mapped to a multimap with the word size as key values. I want to check for each word in that textfile how many words are similar to it but only different by 1 character. The length must be the same so I can figure out all the words of the same length by using the multimap key value. But how would I compare every word that has that key value against every other word in that key_range?

Comment: @user5544610 - I've added a second answer, addressing the updated question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'd be more likely to get assistance if you provided a minimal compilable example. I'm assuming your words are `std::string`s for this answer, but you know what they say about assuming.

There are algorithms like "zip" which is implemented in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) specifically for iterating over mulitple collections simultaneously, but I don't think there's anything comparable in the standard library.

A simple but unpleasantly fiddly approach would be just to manually iterate through both strings. This will output each letter in the two words until either one word ends, or there's a difference.

Note all the fiddly bits: you need to make sure both iterators are valid at all times in case one word ends before the other, and working out what actually happened is a bit cumbersome.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string word1 = "capsicum";
    std::string word2 = "capsicube";

    std::string::iterator it1 = word1.begin();
    std::string::iterator it2 = word2.begin();

    while (it1 != word1.end() && it2 != word2.end())
    {
            // characters are different!
            if (*it1 != *it2)
                    break;

            // characters are the same
            std::cout << "Both have: " << *it1 << std::endl;

            // advance both iterators
            ++it1;
            ++it2;
    }

    if (it1 == word1.end() && it2 == word2.end())
    {
            std::cout << "Words were the same!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (it1 == word1.end())
    {
            std::cout << "Word 1 was shorter than word 2." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (it2 == word2.end())
    {
            std::cout << "Word 1 was longer than word 2." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
            std::cout << "Words were different after position " << (it1 - word1.begin())
                      << ": '" << *it1 << "' vs '" << *it2 << "'" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that kind of helps. But what I'm confused about is that I have a map which is made up of size_t of string as the key, and strings as the value.  Then I have a pair that stores the equal_range for all strings with size of 4. Then I want to iterate through the start of that equal_range to the end of that equal_range.  The start is my pair.first  and end is my pair.second. 
How would I iterate through every character that my pair.first points too and then compare that to every word in between pair.first and pair.second ?

Comment: @user5544610 - could you update your question to include this additional information, preferably in the form of simple but valid code?

Comment: Ok I updated my original question and provided all the code I have written.

Answer (score 0):

New answer, since the question was significantly updated. I'm still not sure this will do exactly what you want, but I think you should be able to use it to get where you want to go.

I've written this as a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is ideally how you should pose your questions. I've also used C++11 features for brevity/readability.

Hopefully the inline comments will explain things sufficiently for you to at least be able to do your own research for anything you don't fully understand, but feel free to comment if you have any more questions. The basic idea is to store the first word (using the `key_range.first` iterator), and then start iterating from the *following* iterator using `std::next()`, until we reach the end iterator in `key_pair.second`.

This then gives us `word1` outside of the loop, and `word2` within the loop which will be set to every other word in the list. We then use the "dual interation" technique I posted in my other answer to compare each word character by character.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::multimap<size_t, std::string> wordMap;

    wordMap.insert({4, "dogs"});
    wordMap.insert({4, "digs"});
    wordMap.insert({4, "does"});
    wordMap.insert({4, "dogs"});
    wordMap.insert({4, "dibs"});

    // original type declaration...
    //  std::pair<std::multimap<size_t, std::string>::iterator, std::multimap<size_t, std::string>::iterator> key_range;

    // C++11 type inference...
    auto key_range = wordMap.equal_range(4);

    // make sure the range wasn't empty
    if (key_range.first == key_range.second)
    {
            std::cerr << "No words in desired range." << std::endl;
            return 1;
    }

    // get a reference to the first word
    std::string const& word1 = key_range.first->second;


    std::cout << "Comparing '" << word1 << "' to..." << std::endl;

    // loop through every iterator from the key_range, skipping for the first
    // (since that's the word we're comparing everything else to)
    for (auto itr = std::next(key_range.first); itr != key_range.second; ++itr)
    {
            // create a reference for clarity
            std::string const& word2 = itr->second;

            std::cout << "... '" << word2 << "'";

            // hit counter; where hit is defined as characters not matching
            int hit = 0;

            // get iterators to the start of each word
            auto witr1 = word1.begin();
            auto witr2 = word2.begin();

            // loop until we reach the end of either iterator. If we're completely
            // confident the two words are the same length, we could only check
            // one of them; but defensive coding is a good idea.
            while (witr1 != word1.end() && witr2 != word2.end())
            {
                    // dereferencing the iterators will yield a char; so compare them
                    if (*witr1 != *witr2)
                            ++hit;

                    // advance both iterators
                    ++witr1;
                    ++witr2;
            }

            // do something depending on the number of hits
            if (hit <= 1)
            {
                    std::cout << " ... close enough!" << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                    std::cout << " ... not a match, " << hit << " hits." << std::endl;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: auto witr1 = word1.begin(); would this be a string iterator ? Just for clarification.

Comment: @user5544610 - yes, it should be equivalent to `std::string::const_iterator witr1 = word1.begin();`

Comment: This is asking a lot but do you think there is any more efficient way to do what I'm trying to do besides comparing every word against every word?

Comment: @user5544610 - ask it as a new question. Include at a minimum: a) where the words are coming from (e.g. user input, predefined dataset, ..?); b) how many words you're dealing with (dozens? thousands? millions?); c) precise definitions of what a 'word' is (are they only alpha, alphanumeric, may include punctuation, might be phrases, etc.) and any assumptions we can make about them (e.g. none are longer than X characters); d) specifications for how to compare/score them, e.g. is it case sensitive, are some characters irrelevant and e) what you actually want to do with the words once compared.

Comment: @user5544610 - Also include runnable example code, and a clear explanation of what's taking too long, how you determined it's taking too long, and whether you need to improve the performance for practical reasons (and state those reasons) or if it's purely an academic question. You might find there's more efficient ways to load in the data, or your end goal can be reached by a completely different process than the one you're trying to use. So, providing information about the constraints you're under is critical.